# Creating recipe in python-for-android for mgrs library

Tags: kivy, buildozer, recipe, python-for-android

I used not pure mgrs library to create my app and I got some problem to import all the dependencies from MGRS package to apk. Is there some way to build recipe to not pure Python packages?

I use buildozer to compile my application